# Jquery slide toggle

Tags: jquery, icons, toggle, slidetoggle

i found a tutorial online, for an slide toggle accordion content div. the only thing is that i would like for a + to show up on the non active tab and a - to show up on a active tab

```
<div id="accordion">

  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content default">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam dolores placerat ea. Sed posse appetere principes ei, sea enim erat eu, mea id erant albucius definitionem. Eu tation erroribus has, te his dolor aliquip assueverit, eam esse aeterno at. Aperiri vivendum consequat vis ne. Ad idque pericula disputationi pri, ignota dissentiunt sea in, pri ut putant mediocrem dissentiunt.
</p>
  </div>


  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam dolores placerat ea. Sed posse appetere principes ei, sea enim erat eu, mea id erant albucius definitionem. Eu tation erroribus has, te his dolor aliquip assueverit, eam esse aeterno at. Aperiri vivendum consequat vis ne. Ad idque pericula disputationi pri, ignota dissentiunt sea in, pri ut putant mediocrem dissentiunt.
</p>
  </div>

  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam dolores placerat ea. Sed posse appetere principes ei, sea enim erat eu, mea id erant albucius definitionem. Eu tation erroribus has, te his dolor aliquip assueverit, eam esse aeterno at. Aperiri vivendum consequat vis ne. Ad idque pericula disputationi pri, ignota dissentiunt sea in, pri ut putant mediocrem dissentiunt.
</p>
  </div>

    <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 4</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam dolores placerat ea. Sed posse appetere principes ei, sea enim erat eu, mea id erant albucius definitionem. Eu tation erroribus has, te his dolor aliquip assueverit, eam esse aeterno at. Aperiri vivendum consequat vis ne. Ad idque pericula disputationi pri, ignota dissentiunt sea in, pri ut putant mediocrem dissentiunt.
</p>
  </div>

    <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 5</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam dolores placerat ea. Sed posse appetere principes ei, sea enim erat eu, mea id erant albucius definitionem. Eu tation erroribus has, te his dolor aliquip assueverit, eam esse aeterno at. Aperiri vivendum consequat vis ne. Ad idque pericula disputationi pri, ignota dissentiunt sea in, pri ut putant mediocrem dissentiunt.
</p>
  </div>


    <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 6</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam dolores placerat ea. Sed posse appetere principes ei, sea enim erat eu, mea id erant albucius definitionem. Eu tation erroribus has, te his dolor aliquip assueverit, eam esse aeterno at. Aperiri vivendum consequat vis ne. Ad idque pericula disputationi pri, ignota dissentiunt sea in, pri ut putant mediocrem dissentiunt.
</p>
  </div>


</div>



$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');




    });
});



h4 {

font-size:25px;
font-weight:bold;

margin-left:4%;
color:#000000;
}

.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .accordion-content {display: none;}
  .accordion-content.default {display: block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjn4okkd/

Answer (score 0):

replace your javascript & jquery by this :

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
checkActive();
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {

    if ($(this).find('b').text() == '+ ') {
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-content").slideUp('slow',function() {
            $(this).prev().find('b').text('- '); 
        });
    }
    else {
    //Expand or collapse this panel
       $(this).next().slideToggle('slow',function() {
            $(this).prev().find('b').text('+ '); 
        }); 

    //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow',function() {
            $(this).prev().find('b').text('- '); 
        });
    }
});
});

function checkActive() {
 $('.accordion-toggle').each(function (index, element) {
 if ($(element).next().css('display') == 'block') {
     $(element).html('<b>+ </b>' + $(element).text());
 }
 else {
     $(element).html('<b>- </b>' + $(element).text());
 }
});   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eayx/oeb5d2xx/

This script replace b tab to headers and add + and - on b tag.

Comment: Thank you Pichet for your response but when the tab is active like it has been selected the + is still beside the title. this  is incorrect  it should be a - when the tab is selected and only that tab should have a - beside the title. the other tabs that are not active should have a + beside them at all times unless they are selected. THANKYOU

Comment: Not problem , I think you just switch + and - , it should be fine.[link] (http://jsfiddle.net/eayx/bwm39o33/)

Comment: Thank you Pichet that is awesome. would i be able to style the + - using css?

Comment: for some reason it is not working in my wordpress site. the old code was perfectly